# Count Rows with a specific condition without moving Rows (PySpark)

Tags: if-statement, pyspark, filter, conditional-statements

As literally I am new at programming or at least I new the basics, I am facing an issue, that I do not know how to count the "cycles" that i have in a PySpark datafrme.

Let´s suppose that this is the DataFrame:

| letter | group |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0 |
| A | 0 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 0 |
| A | 0 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 0 |
| A | 0 |

The result that I would like to see is how many "cycles (Two or X #1 are consecutive)". In this case would be:

- 2 Cycles (Table Below, shows the "Cycles" separated).

How can I achieve this result?

| letter | group |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0 |
| A | 0 |
| ------ | ----- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| ------ | ----- |
| A | 0 |
| A | 0 |
| ------ | ----- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 1 |
| ------ | ----- |
| A | 0 |
| A | 0 |

If you can help me with an example or a link if this was already mentioned would be appreciated.

I already tried several filters but I was unsuccessful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there are 5 cycles aren't there? where. 2 or more values of "group" that are equal = 1 cycle for the same letter) but what happens if the "group" changes on each row e.g 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 etc. are such rows just ignored?

Comment: @PaulMaxwell, correct, there are 5 cycles, but for the purpose of this exercise 0 is not counted and the focus is only on 1, in the case of having 1,0,1,0,1, those rows need to be ignored as the only ones to be counted are in the case of 2 or more consecutive 1´s.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to retain the current row order so that you count the cycles. For this there is a function `monotonically_increasing_id()` that can be used to assign a unique and "increasing value" for each row so that is we sort by that column the original row sequence is retained. Once that is in place we can use window based calculations (that require sorting rows) to provide the cycle counts.

nb: not sure about the 2 consecutive row requirement, that isn't dealt with below

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# Create SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
          .appName('CycleCount') \
          .getOrCreate()

# Assume "df" as the DataFrame
df.show()

# Create a new column "index" so that we can retain the current row order
df = df.withColumn("index", F.monotonically_increasing_id())

# Define the window ordered by the "index" which retains current row order (per letter)
window = Window.partitionBy("letter").orderBy("index")

# Add new column "change" that flags when a change in 'group' occurs
df = df.withColumn("change", F.when(F.lag("group").over(window) != F.col("group"), 1).otherwise(0))

# Use cumsum() for cumulative sum of these changes, which will serve as an identifier for each cycle
df = df.withColumn("cycle", F.sum("change").over(window))

# Filter out groups with only 1 row
df = df.filter(F.col("count") > 1)

# Count the number of cycles
cycle_count = df.groupBy("letter", "cycle").count().count()

print("Number of cycles: ", cycle_count)
```

Comment: I tried this solution, and it worked perfectly, however when I had the case where I just had one "1" the program counted it, how can I define a specific "condition" in this case only more than two consecutive "1"? Thanks a lot.

Comment: include a filter for rows where count is greater than 1 see `df = df.filter(F.col("count") > 1)` - added into the answer just before the cycle_count is calculated